# How can I merge two arrays and make them array of objects in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, ecmascript-6

I have a simple question. I have two arrays A and B, I want to return array of object with mixing the two arrays.

**For example:**

```
let a = [ 1, 2 ]

let b = [ 3, 4 ]
```

**Expected result**:

```
const C = [
   { 
      a: 1,
      b: 3 
   },
   { 
      a: 2,
      b: 4 
   }
]
```

How can I do this?

I tried to forloop A then B and assign everytime but it didn't work.

Comment: _"I tried to forloop A then B and assign everytime but it didn't work."_ - You've missed to add this part as well -> [mcve]

Comment: Map and get the value of index from the second array: `const merged = a.map((value, index) => ({a: value, b: b[index]}))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array map method on one of the array and use `index` to retrieve the element from the second array

```js
let a = [1, 2]

let b = [3, 4];


let c = a.map((item, index) => {
  return {
    a: item,
    b: b[index]
  }

});

console.log(c)
```

Comment: Thanks brother this did the tric

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```js
let a = [1, 2];
let b = [3, 4];

// From @brk. This transforms each element of a to an object containing a's value and b's value
let c = a.map((item, index) => {
  a: item,
  b: b[index]
});

// Another way. Iterates through each element 
for (let i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
  c[i].a = a[i];
  c[i].b = b[i];
}

// Yet another. A combination of the first two.
for (let [index, item] of Object.entries(a)) {
  c[index] = {
    a: item,
    b: b[index]
  };
}
```

There's certainly a more elegant solution, but it evades me at the moment